# How to assign controller name and action name dynamically in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to assign controller name and action name dynamically in asp.net mvc

Comment: Dynamically to what? when? Give an example

Comment: Im writing my own route handler ...in that i want to specify action name ...depending upon my requirements

Answer (score 1):

On HttpApplication.Application_Start your can add dynamically any routes (Controller and Action anme) to RouteTable.Routes, this you can use any information available in this event or ever populate routes from [config file](http://andrewmyhre.wordpress.com/2008/08/02/load-aspnet-mvc-routes-dynamically-at-runtime-from-a-repository/) or [database](http://www.iansuttle.com/blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-Store-Routes-in-the-Database.aspx).
For example

```
new Route( "Admin/{actionName}/{slug}/", CreateRouteHandler())  
{  
   Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),  
   Url = new RouteValueDictionary(dataTokens)  
}
```

You couldn't change actions in RouteHandler, you could process current HttpRequest in your different ways, [for example](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx).